# Does the compiler manage duplicate types generated with template meta-programming

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

In the following code, I split a variadic template in two `typeList`'s, the definition of typeList and putLeft are not important.

```
template<typename ...SL>
struct split {
    static const size_t size = sizeof...(SL);
    typedef typename putLeft<typeList<>,size/2, typeList<SL...>>::result firstHalf;
    typedef typename putLeft<typeList<>,size/2, typeList<SL...>>::rest secondHalf;
};
```

what I want to know is when I use `putLeft<typeList<>,size/2, typeList<SL...>>::result` and `putLeft<typeList<>,size/2, typeList<SL...>>::rest` later, does the compiler manage the duplicate struct that is `putLeft<typeList<>,size/2, typeList<SL...>>::result`, or does it compute the struct again ?

Comment: Shouldn't rest be: `typedef typename putLeft<typeList<>,size-size/2, typeList<SL...>>::rest secondHalf;` to handle odd sizes?

Comment: @NathanOliver Presumably `rest` is actually the rest after the `size/2`?

Comment: @Barry Yes, but that doesn't have to do anything with the question, I only need to know if the compiler will compute the struct again

Comment: @NathanOliver when I compute the first half, I already have th second half, both are stored in `putLeft<typeList<>,size/2, typeList<SL...>>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler will only instantiate `putLeft<typeList<>,size/2, typeList<SL...>>` once, at the point where you need the `result` type name.

However, it would probably be worth taking an alias to that so that you don't typo it on the second line:

```
template<typename ...SL>
struct split {
    static const size_t size = sizeof...(SL);
    using impl = putLeft<typeList<>,size/2, typeList<SL...>>;

    using firstHalf = typename impl::result;
    using secondHalf = typename impl::rest;
};
```

It won't have any effect on what actually happens, but readers of your code will thank you.

Comment: What does typo mean ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun There's no error *now*. But that doesn't mean you couldn't add one in the future, here or somewhere else. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 1):

Modern compilers avoid recompilation. This helps keep compilation times down.

Older compilers recompiled the same type repeatedly, but that did not affect the correctness of the program. They just discarded duplicates in a later stage.